# Insertion failure in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in CodeIgniter and want to insert data into my table. But I'm not able to do so. Have configured the database.
Any help would be appreciated.

Controller - show.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Show extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('you_view');

    }

    public function get() 
            {
        $this->load->model('show_model');
        if ($this->input->post('submit')) 
            {

                $this->show_model->insert();
        }
        redirect('show');
}

}

?>
```

Model - show_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Show_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function insert($dbdata)
    {
        $name=  $this->input->post('name');
        $surname=  $this->input->post('surname');
        $data=array(
            'name'=>$name,
            'surname'=>$surname
        );
        $this->db->insert('user', $data);
    }


}
?>
```

View - you_view.php

```
<?php
        echo form_open('show/get', array('name' => 'myform'));    
    ?>
<form name="form1" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="name"/> 
    <input type="text" name="surname"/> 
    <button name="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php
    echo form_close();
    ?>
```

database.php -

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'simple';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? And remove `$dbdata` from your model function as you are not passing any value from your controller to model function

Comment: No data is being inserted in the database.

Comment: Show your database.php

Comment: Have added it. Name of database is simple. It has table user having 3 fields. One is id (autoincrement), name and surname.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your valuable time and answers! :)

Comment: @Undervoter: Can I know the reason as to why you undervoted the question?

Answer (score 3):

when you call

```
echo form_open();
```

You don't need any `<form>` tag anymore 
And in your model change

```
function insert($dbdata)
```

to

```
function insert($table,$data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($table,$data);

        if($this->db->affected_rows() >0){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

in controller you just need

```
public function get() 
            {
        $this->load->model('show_model');
        if ($this->input->post('name') && $this->input->post('surname')) 
            {
$u = $this->input->post('name');
$sur = $this->input->post('surname');
   $array = array(
'field1'=>$u,
'field2'=>$sur //your feild in your table
);
              $q =   $this->show_model->insert('yourTable',$array);

       if($q === true) redirect('show');
}
```

May it helps

Answer (score 0):

you did n't pass data to model insert function. check below line

```
$this->show_model->insert();
```

But you have parameter in model function.
Instead of preparing data array in model, you should do in controller itself. You should not use post in model.

```
if ($this->input->post('submit')) 
{
   $name=  $this->input->post('name');
   $surname=  $this->input->post('surname');
   $data=array(
            'name'=>$name,
            'surname'=>$surname
       );
  $this->show_model->insert($data);
}
```

Remove below lines in model:

```
        $name=  $this->input->post('name');
        $surname=  $this->input->post('surname');
        $data=array(
            'name'=>$name,
            'surname'=>$surname
        );
```

Comment: I did what you said. Moved code from model to controller and added parameter but the data is not inserted into the table.

Comment: did you print last query in insert function? `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: I'll add it but where do I see this query that will be formed?

Comment: you can see in browser itself. use `echo $this->db->last_query();exit;`

Answer (score 0):

In your model replace

```
function insert($dbdata)
```

with

```
function insert()
```

This is because in your controller you are calling model function as

```
$this->show_model->insert();
```

where you have not passed any argument to the model function.

Comment: In model, POST/GET/SESSION kind of logic should not be used as per MVC method.

Comment: I had used if(isset($_POST['submit'])) before but didn't get required result.

Comment: In your view file remove the html `<form>` tags as you are using codeigniter's form tag already.

Comment: I did but din't get my result.

Answer (score 0):

You should get input data in Controller and send it to your model.
Something like:

```
if ($this->input->post('submit')) 
        {
            $this->show_model->insert(array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'),'surname'=>$this->input->post('surname');));
    }
```

In model:

```
$this->db->insert('user', $dbdata);
```

Of course, also you need to trim() and htmlspecialchars() before inserting db, but it's another history.

Comment: There's one error. There won't be a semicolon after ('surname'). Otherwise it worked. Earlier I was taking values from form in $data (array) and then passing it into insert. Why didn't it help me when both are the same things? By the way your solution worked. Thanks! :)

Comment: @user3273794 How did you do it? Code sample pls. Firstly, you should just know, that working with input data happens in controller. Everything you do in Model is queries to DB.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {                           
            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $surname = $this->input->post('surname');
            $data = array(
                'name' => $name,
                'surname' => $surname
            );
            $this->show_model->insert($data);

Answer (score 0):

```
echo form_open(); can be used instead of `<form>` tag.. Don't use `<form>` tag then..
```

Also you are not passing any parameters from the function `insert()` in the controller to the model.. But you use it in model function.. Please don't do that..

If you are in localhost, please visit the userguide in your codeigniter directory . It may be like localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.4/user_guide/

thank you

Answer (score 0):

In View page, call the function using form_open.

It will send the given data to controller page

`<?php echo form_open('controller_page/insert'); ?>`

In Controller page,

`$this->load->Model('model_page');

$name = $this->input->post('name');

$surname = $this->input->post('surname');

```
    $this->model_page->insert($name,$surname);`
```

In Model Page,

`function insert($name,$surname)

{

// Give your insert query

}
`

Use like above code, it will works...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps . Do form validation also and before inserting the data sanitize it

Controller - show.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Show extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('you_view');
    }

    public function get() {
        $this->load->model('show_model');
        if ($this->input->post('submit')) {

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','Name','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('surname','Surname','trim|required');
            if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
                // DO WHAT YOU WANT TO DO IF NO DATA IS ENTERED
            }else{
                $data=array(
                    'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                    'surname'=>$this->input->post('surname')
                );
                $result=$this->Show_model->insert($data);
            }
        }
        redirect('show');
    }

} ?>
```

Model - show_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Show_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function insert($dbdata){

        $this->db->insert('user', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

View - you_view.php

```
<?php echo form_open('show/get', array('name' => 'myform'));
      echo form_input('name',,);
      echo form_input('surname',,);
      echo form_submit('submit','Submit'); 
      echo form_close();
?>
```